# Selenium SQL Database Connection

Tags: java, sql, selenium, testng

I'm running into an issue when I try to run a simple Selenium test that connects to a SQL database. The test will not run, it seems to fail on compiling but does not provide any information on where the error was encountered.

I've looked into this http://automationtricks.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-pass-parameters-to-junit-or.html and Google groups but can't figure it out.

Here's the code, hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
package com.XXX.Tests;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;


public class SeleniumandDB extends SeleneseTestBase {

  @BeforeClass
    public void setUp()throws Exception {

        SeleniumServer seleniumServer=null;
        try {
                seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
                seleniumServer.start();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                   selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://wwww-test/");
                   selenium.start();
                   }




    @Test public void testUntitled2() throws Exception {
        String userID = null;
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;


        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.windowFocus();
        selenium.windowMaximize();

                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XXXX:1433/XXX","XX","XXXX");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM webuser ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                    while(rs.next()){
                            userID = rs.getString("UserID");
                            conn.close();
                            System.out.println(userID);

        selenium.type("txtUserID", userID);
        selenium.type("txtPassword", "password");
        selenium.click("btnLogin2");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000"); 
        selenium.stop();


    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.it should work.
1) remove - extends SeleneseTestBase and then run with junit 
(because @Test Annotation from JUNIT will play the role)

OR

2)just remove @Test annotation and override setUp() and some other methods like start()
Of selenesetestbase class methods and run the class using JUNIT container.

3)OR use TESTNG only. (do not extend class and make use of ANNOTATIONS)

The problem I could see from your explanation and your code is,
You are importing 2 containers (TestNG and Junit4) and you are extending the Test class
With Junit3 container.

And defined the test cases with Junit4 container( by using @Test)
But running the test class using junit3 container.so junit3 needs those default methods to understand which one
Is setUp and which method is a testcase.but you are not supplieg such info
Junit3 container is simply running your class without any testcases.

I hope this will clear the issue.but I might be wrong as I use TestNG and dont extend any classes.

Comment: Brilliant. I actually rewrote the script in another package and it worked. I was still puzzled as why this one did not work. I did not notice I was importing two containers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
package DBCONN;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBCONN {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DBCONN dbconn = new DBCONN();
        dbconn.open();
        dbconn.run();
        dbconn.close();
    }

    // Connection object
    static Connection con = null;
    // Statement object
    private static Statement stmt;
    // Constant for Database URL
    public static String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:Port#:SID";
    // Constant for Database Username
    public static String DB_USER = "username";
    // Constant for Database Password
    public static String DB_PASSWORD = "password";

    public static String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE;

    public void open() throws Exception {
        try {
            // Make the database connection
            String dbClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
            System.out.println("Connecting to database");
            Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
            // Get connection to DB
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            // Statement object to send the SQL statement to the Database
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection to the database");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        try {

            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            res.next();
            System.out.print(res.getString(1));

            System.out.print("\t" + res.getString(2));

            System.out.print("\t" + res.getString(3));

            System.out.println("\t" + res.getString(4));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection to the database");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public void close() throws Exception {
        try {

            con.close();
            System.out.println("Closed connection to the database");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing connection to the database");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in your classpath.

Comment: Yes. I can execute the query from another class in the same package. Query only, it does not include the TestNG framework.